# addplot3[surf] not able to plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I know it might be a basic question for most of you but I just recently started using pgfplots and have no experience whatsoever.

I'm trying to plot a 3D-surface with following coordinates and code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar,colormap/jet, xmin = -0.2,xmax = 1.2,xmajorgrids,
ymin= -0.2,ymax = 1.2,ymajorgrids,zmin = 0.0,
zmax =1.0,zmajorgrids,title=Resultierender Zustand]
\addplot3[surf] table {
0 0 0
0 0.125 0
0 0.25 0
0 0.375 0
0 0.5 0
0 0.625 0
0 0.75 0
0 0.875 0
0 1 0

0.125 0 0
0.125 0.125 0.0227636
0.125 0.25 0.0704405
0.125 0.375 0.0810631
0.125 0.5 0.0825012
0.125 0.625 0.0847161
0.125 0.75 0.059342
0.125 0.875 0.0115338
0.125 1 0

0.25 0 0
0.25 0.125 0.0704405
0.25 0.25 0.239427
0.25 0.375 0.293824
0.25 0.5 0.299262
0.25 0.625 0.297564
0.25 0.75 0.228341
0.25 0.875 0.059342
0.25 1 0

0.375 0 0
0.375 0.125 0.0810631
0.375 0.25 0.293824
0.375 0.375 0.373863
0.375 0.5 0.379686
0.375 0.625 0.376929
0.375 0.75 0.297564
0.375 0.875 0.0847161
0.375 1 0

0.5 0 0
0.5 0.125 0.0825012
0.5 0.25 0.299262
0.5 0.375 0.379686
0.5 0.5 0.383375
0.5 0.625 0.379686
0.5 0.75 0.299262
0.5 0.875 0.0825012
0.5 1 0

0.625 0 0
0.625 0.125 0.0847161
0.625 0.25 0.297564
0.625 0.375 0.376929
0.625 0.5 0.379686
0.625 0.625 0.373863
0.625 0.75 0.293824
0.625 0.875 0.0810631
0.625 1 0

0.75 0 0
0.75 0.125 0.059342
0.75 0.25 0.228341
0.75 0.375 0.297564
0.75 0.5 0.299262
0.75 0.625 0.293824
0.75 0.75 0.239427
0.75 0.875 0.0704405
0.75 1 0

0.875 0 0
0.875 0.125 0.0115338
0.875 0.25 0.059342
0.875 0.375 0.0847161
0.875 0.5 0.0825012
0.875 0.625 0.0810631
0.875 0.75 0.0704405
0.875 0.875 0.0227636
0.875 1 0

1 0 0
1 0.125 0
1 0.25 0
1 0.375 0
1 0.5 0
1 0.625 0
1 0.75 0
1 0.875 0
1 1 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting image is as follows:[image: plot]

And is obviously wrong..
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in beforehand

### Two different `views` :

First is ok
[image]
Second is broken
[image]

Comment: This display issue seems to be dependent upon the viewing angle. Setting `view={20}{60}` gives a proper display, and faulty behavior appears for `view={20}{50}`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but unfortunately I'm trying to plot a solution of a nonstationary PDE. The plot therefore varies from time to time and I'd like to have a more "consistent" solution if possible.
But thanks again!

Comment: Try adding [mesh/ordering=y varies] to the axis options.

Comment: Wonderful! Your solution solved the problem permanently, @JohnKormylo! 
I'm really grateful for your tip! 
If you happen to have the patience, I'd appreciate if you could explain my fault/your solution.
Anyways, thanks for I can now plot to my heart's content!

Comment: For 3D you want to plot from back to front in order to hide the points which should be hidden.  Your data was given in side-to-side order.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.